# How to invoke a function on an object dynamically by name?

Tags: python

In Python, say I have a string that contains the name of a class function that I know a particular object will have, how can I invoke it?

That is:

```
obj = MyClass() # this class has a method doStuff()
func = "doStuff"
# how to call obj.doStuff() using the func variable?
```

Comment: I'm curious about why you would need to do this. This sounds like you may be doing something the hard way. Could you elaborate on your situation?

Comment: I have a cli app where I want to accept commands from the command line, but don't want to do something like: "if command = 'doThing' then obj.doThing() elseif command = 'someOtherThing' ... and so on. I want to add methods to the handler class and then they'd automatically be available on the cli

Comment: is that alright to do that? what situations would this approach not a good idea? i'm in a similar situation too, but i'm not sure if i'll go this way. somehow, i feel that it would be more clearer if i explicitly use branching instead. what do you think? thanks!

Answer (score 111, accepted):

Use the `getattr` built-in function. See the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html?highlight=getattr#getattr)

```py
obj = MyClass()
try:
    func = getattr(obj, "dostuff")
    func()
except AttributeError:
    print("dostuff not found")
```

Comment: This link is also having a useful and an important example of the above question https://gist.github.com/hygull/41f94e64b84f96fa01d04567e27eb46b

Comment: Works well for a call but didn't find the way for assigning a value to the method. Eg: `obj."dostuff" = x`

Comment: Answering to myself : Didn't know either SETATTR. So `func = setattr(obj, "dostuff",  x)` will do the job