# How to run a user input MATLAB function in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, matlab, matlab-compiler

Based on the example given in the [documentation](https://au.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/call-user-script-and-function-from-python.html), we can call a MATLAB file 
`triarea.m` from a python script as follows:

```
import matlab.engine
eng = matlab.engine.start_matlab()
eng.triarea(nargout=0)
```

What if, we had a variable in Python with the MATLAB filename input by the user,
`file_name = 'triarea'`
then,

```
eng.file_name(nargout=0)
```

returns the error

> MatlabExecutionError: Undefined function 'file_name' for input
>   arguments of type 'double'.

How can we run the user input MATLAB function in Python?

In my actual problem, the file_name is input while instantiating an object of a class and is stored as an object attribute. Then one of the methods of the object calls this MATLAB file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the builtin function `gettatr` like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3951850/5124383):

```
import matlab.engine
eng = matlab.engine.start_matlab()

file_name = 'triarea'
dynamic_func = getattr(eng, file_name)
dynamic_func(nargout=0)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This worked like a charm for me. I was unaware of this function.

Answer (score 1):

You can combine Python's f strings and eval.

An example which uses the function name, in this case [plot](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot.html) directly:

```
eng.plot(eng.magic(4))
```

An example which evaluates the variable name as the function name:

```
file_name = 'plot'
eval(f'eng.{file_name}(eng.magic(4))')
```